# When does copper leach to water? Conflicting faqs

Tags: water

I have heard conflicting reports:

1. Copper leaches to water only when the water is high in acid or the Copper is corroded.
2. Copper leaches to water any time, especially when it is new copper or the water is hot.

Which one would be correct?

Comment: It depends on what you consider as leaching *quantitatively*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second answer would be correct in an analytical context as the auto-ionization of water decreases in pH as temperature increases. And new copper does not have the surface of reacted material to shield the metal underneath, as such, scenario 2 always occurs, scenario one occurs faster, however, it's conditional statement that the water be acidic and the copper be corroded are invalid.

Cheers,

Comment: Since #2 is true, how do cities that use copper piping and keep the water from getting to much copper?

Comment: The amount of copper dissolved is not toxic, just adds the characteristic “city water” flavor

Comment: What about a espresso machine with a copper boiler? Would the heat make the water, along with sitting water for hours,  absorb more copper and be toxic?

Answer (score 0):

Don't they sell copper tea kettles? This implies copper does not dissolve appreciably, even in hot water.

But have you seen houses with those copper rain gutters and downspouts that pour out rainwater onto concrete patios? You know, where the concrete turns that nasty-looking green color? Could be due to acid rain. Now acid rain may be acidic, but I would not say highly acidic. Maybe copper just dissolves a little and gets immediately precipitated by the alkaline concrete. So, lots of copper surface and lots of water can give evidence of copper dissolution over some period of time.

So, different results; but that's life.

Comment: Copper roofs do not lose copper; they build up a greenish patina which is a complex combination of copper oxides ,carbonates , hydroxides  , etc.

Comment: I'm surprised that copper stains are not more prevalent, but the second picture on google showed stains on concrete from runoff that looked like from a downspout. I added it to the answer.